# how to write command using SubInACL to allow non admin user to use WAMP server?

Tags: windows, wamp

I found these lines in [link](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,38354,72169):

```
subinacl /SERVICE \\MachineName\wampapache /GRANT=domainname.com\username=F
subinacl /SERVICE \\MachineName\wampmysql /GRANT=domainname.com\username=F
```

but i dont get the `domainname.com`

Please make me a SubInACL command with my params (computer name: `chiny-Komputer`;
non admin user name: `chiny`)

Comment: Just omit the domain name part if you're not in a domain environment so based on what you provided, it looks like it'd be `subinacl /SERVICE \\chiny-Komputer\wampapache /GRANT=chiny=F` and `subinacl /SERVICE \\chiny-Komputer\wampmysql /GRANT=chiny=F`. I'm not used to this tool so this is based on the detail you provided only... test to confirm all works as expected. You may need to get an admin on the computer to run this though and confirm that subinacl is on this machine to even us the tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> subinacl /SERVICE \\MachineName\wampapache /GRANT=domainname.com\username=F
> subinacl /SERVICE \\MachineName\wampmysql /GRANT=domainname.com\username=F
> ```
>
> Please make me a SubInACL command with my params (computer name:
>   `chiny-Komputer`; non admin user name: `chiny`)

Just omit the domain name part if you're not in a domain environment so based on what you provided, it looks like it'd be:

`subinacl /SERVICE \\chiny-Komputer\wampapache /GRANT=chiny=F`

`subinacl /SERVICE \\chiny-Komputer\wampmysqld /GRANT=chiny=F`

I'm not used to this tool so this is based on the detail you provided only. Test to confirm all works as expected. You may need to get an admin on the computer to run this though and confirm that subinacl is on this machine to even us the tool